# Stack Overflow mirror site

Tags: discussion, legal

I found a mirror in Russian, e.g.

1. Stack Overflow: [Golang time.Ticker, how to begin on even timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267106/golang-time-ticker-how-to-begin-on-even-timestamps)
2. coderoad: https://coderoad.ru/33267106/Golang-time-Ticker-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8

It is just a translation of the pages from Stack Overflow.
I am not sure if it's legal.

Comment: Does it have the required attribution (I haven't looked)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen it seems to have a source to the question on StackOverflow below each question over there. For instance, [this one](https://coderoad.ru/927358/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-Git) on the copy website has a "source" link at the bottom. I don't think it has the required attribution, though.